# Callback in PHP - I need explanation

Tags: php, callback

I found code similar to this:

```
function function_1($callback) 
{
    // not related code removed

    $callback($p);

}
```

**How to call this function? What shall I put in `$callback` parameter?**

Lets say, I want to use function called `function_2($p)`.

Comment: The `$callback` parameter is a reference to the function you'd like to invoke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the full explanation you want, straight from the php docs: [Callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

If you're on php 5.3+, you can pass a lambda (aka anonymous function):

```
<?php function_1(function ($p) { ... });
```

If you need support for previous versions of php, you need to define a regular function or instance method. Since the code you've shown is using `$callback()` instead of `call_user_func($callback)`, you shouldn't need this.

```
<?php

// without a class
function function_2 ($p) { ... }
function_1('function_2');

// with a class
class A {
    public function function_2 ($p) { ... }

    public function doIt () {
        function_1(array($this, 'function_2'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run it:

```
function function_2() 
{
    echo 'done';

}


function function_1($callback) 
{
    // not related code removed

    call_user_func($callback);

}

function_1("function_2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function test($param)
{
}

function function_1($callback) 
{
    // not related code removed

    $callback($p);

}

function_1("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

in older php versions, you would call it with

```
function_1("function_2");
```

but in php 5.3, you could do

```
$function_2 = function($p) {
};

function_1($function_2);
```

For further reference, read [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), [Callbacks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) and [call_user_func](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) in the PHP manual.

Comment: nitpick: anonymous functions since 5.3. ;)